# Unable to update msal from 1.2.1 to 1.5.1 on Android

Tags: android, azure-ad-msal

I am trying to update msal version from 1.2.0 to 1.5.1 on Android but I am getting following error:

> Could not resolve com.microsoft.device.display:display-mask:0.3.0.

What can I try to fix this?

Answer (score 3):

This is known according to here: https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-android/issues/1027

I would think this will apply to 1.5.1 as well. it seems you have 2 options, someone worked around it https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-android/issues/1027#issuecomment-621893161

and the other is based on the changelog: 
for details: https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-android/issues/1027#issuecomment-621921447

> For apps that would like to include their own copy of Surface Duo SDK,
>   please exclude the SDK inside MSAL to avoid conflicts. implementation
>   ("com.microsoft.identity.client:msal:1.5.0") { exclude group:
>   'com.microsoft.device.display' }

then you need to add something in the gradle.

Comment: For me *implementation ("com.microsoft.identity.client:msal:2.+") {exclude group: 'com.microsoft.device.display'}* worked very well too.

Comment: After doing this I got an error as below,
Duplicate class androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelLazy found in modules jetified-lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx-2.2.0-runtime (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.2.0) and lifecycle-viewmodel-2.5.1-runtime (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.5.1)

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution!
Change your sdk version from 21 to 26 in build.gradle
Good Luck!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s2mJH.png)